# Loading xml files into relational database

Tags: xml, database, informatica

I am trying to load xml files into a relational database through Informatica Powercenter. Can anybody share your insights/thoughts regarding the same how we can accomplish it.

Comment: Hi Yea... I get the error as below when I import the xml file.

Comment: FATAL: Error at (file C:/AARP/Data Files/DART/SampleDartFileByAPI.xml, line 39749, char 24 ): An exception occurred! Type:UTFDataFormatException, Message:invalid byte 1 (’) of a 1-byte sequence..

Comment: I don't have access to PowerCenter at the moment but aren't you supposed to import an XSD file? What's inside `SampleDartFileByAPI.xml` - data or schema definition?

Comment: I have data inside my xml file.